# List the employees whose salary is same as the salary of names ram or sham

Tags: sql

List the `employees` whose salary is same as the salary of "ram"  or "sham".

**Here are the table details:**

```
emp_id, emp_name, job_name, salary
```

**Here is my query:**

```
select * 
from employees 
where salary = (select salary 
                  from employees
                 where emp_name ='sham' or emp_name = 'ram');
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: when I fire the above query not able to get the exact answer can you help me on that

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
from employees 
where salary IN 
(
  select salary  
  from employees 
  where emp_name IN ('sham', 'ram')
);
```